# ESRI pgdb in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ogr, personal-geodatabase

Using OSGeo4W 1.5, when I go to add vector layer and select file type,
navigate to my ESRI pgdb. I get a not a valid or recognized data source.

If I use the database type I get a page that defaults back to type odbc even
though I just chose esri personal geodatabase in the previous dialog, it
also requires host, database, port.

There seems to be no way to navigate to a file.

The help file is also blank and says new ogr database connection dialog.

Do I not have all the ogr support installed?

Has anyone looked into adding support for FME in QGIS? I use it to connect to many formats in all my other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works from in QGIS 1.6 from OSGeo4W.  Add vector layer -> File: c:\path\to\mdb

Are you sure it's a Personal Geodatabase (.mdb)?

Comment: not sure why I couldn't get it to work the other day. All good now.

Comment: I wonder why the option to select esri personal db is in the other dialog (database)?